# Why doesn't this URL pattern match?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using a pattern as described by John Gruber in this [daringfireball article](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) to auto link URLs in user comments.

I'm using it with PHP to match URLs, and want it to match a single TLD with no `www` and no trailing slash, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the pattern (and can be seen in more detail at the article above):

```
$pattern  = '#(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4})(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))#';
```

Specifically I'm looking at this particular subpattern: `[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}`

This subpattern works separately, but as a part of the larger pattern, it doesn't match `google.com`.

Comment: Even if you can get it to match `google.com`, it certainly won't match, for example, `annebjerggaard.museum`.

Comment: you know you must escape all . characters right?

Comment: The dots are inside square brackets, so the OP is okay.

Comment: Is t possible that you are overcomplifying things? I am sure there are simpler patterns to match url's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}` works as you expect, but the rest of the pattern requires at least 1 following character:

```
google.com/
google.com?lang=en-us
google.com#!foo/bar
```

etc.

You can try allowing the tail to be optional, but it may in turn give you false-positives rather than excluding false-negatives:

```
$pattern  = '#...“”‘’])?)#';  # '...' for brevity
#                      ^
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I ended up doing what you mentioned and instead of matching `[a-z]{2,4}`, I just specified some domain suffixes so as not to match false-positives.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

http://regexr.com?2uica

Are you sure there is nothing in you php that is tripping you up?

**EDIT**

It's because the full pattern expects to find something before the domain name, like `http://` or `www`

Comment: The subpattern there works when it's by itself, but doesn't when it's a part of the larger pattern, try it.